# Custom domain name and wildcard DNS

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I have a web application that uses subdomains for user profiles (ex. noodles.example.com). I have a wildcard DNS configured in Nginx. Everything is working fine with that.

How would a user be able to point his own domain to my server IP address and get his profile? How would such a scenario work?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't, at least not how you've currently designed things.

You'll need to not use name-based vhosts, and instead accept all host headers at the webserver level. Then deal with routing requests with certain host headers properly within your application.